# Fiware cygnus: no data have been persisted in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I am trying to use cygnus with Mongo DB, but no data have been persisted in the data base.
Here is the notification got in cygnus:

```
15/07/21 14:48:01 INFO handlers.OrionRestHandler: Starting transaction (1437482681-118-0000000000)
15/07/21 14:48:01 INFO handlers.OrionRestHandler: Received data ({  "subscriptionId" : "55a73819d0c457bb20b1d467",  "originator" : "localhost",  "contextResponses" : [    {      "contextElement" : {        "type" : "enocean",        "isPattern" : "false",        "id" : "enocean:myButtonA",        "attributes" : [          {            "name" : "ButtonValue",            "type" : "",            "value" : "ON",            "metadatas" : [              {                "name" : "TimeInstant",                "type" : "ISO8601",                "value" : "2015-07-20T21:29:56.509293Z"              }            ]          }        ]      },      "statusCode" : {        "code" : "200",        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"      }    }  ]})
15/07/21 14:48:01 INFO handlers.OrionRestHandler: Event put in the channel (id=1454120446, ttl=10)
```

Here is my agent configuration:

```
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = OrionMongoSink
cygnusagent.channels = mongo-channel 

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel 
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# TimestampInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# GroupinInterceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Grouping rules for the GroupingInterceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /home/egm_demo/usr/fiware-cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionMongoSink configuration
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoSink
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
# FQDN/IP:port where the MongoDB server runs (standalone case) or comma-separated list of FQDN/IP:port pairs where the MongoDB replica set members run
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = 127.0.0.1:27017
# a valid user in the MongoDB server (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username =
# password for the user above (or empty if authentication is not enabled in MongoDB)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
# prefix for the MongoDB databases
#cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = kura
# prefix pro the MongoDB collections
#cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = button
# true is collection names are based on a hash, false for human redable collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.should_hash = false

# ============================================
# mongo-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Here is my rule :

```
{
    "grouping_rules": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fields": [
                "button"
            ],
            "regex": ".*",            
            "destination": "kura",
            "fiware_service_path": "/kuraspath"
        }

     ]
}
```

Any ideas of what I have missed? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration parameter is wrong:

```
cygnusagent.sinks = OrionMongoSink
```

According to your configuration, it must be `mongo-sink` (I mean, you are configuring a Mongo sink named `mongo-sink` when you configure lines such as `cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.type`).

In addition, I would recommend you to not using the grouping rules feature; it is an advanced feature about sending the data to a collection different than the default one, and in a first stage I would play with the default behaviour. Thus, my recommendation is to leave the path to the file in `cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file`, but comment all the JSON within it :)